# How to load data according to data in recyclerview android java

Tags: java, android, google-cloud-firestore, android-recyclerview

I am very new to android and Firebase

**So My Problem is: I have a RecylerView like this:**

> Note: I am Loading data from Firebase Firestore so please give answer according to that

[image: RecyclerView Image]

**And I want *if anyone click on Pizza* then pizza's data should be load like this:**

[image: pizza clicked]

> If you have any question or doubt related to my question feel free to ask in comment.

How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you provide the data model you are using in your RecyclerView's adapter? I imagine that you may have something like this (this is just an example):

```
{
   "id": 123123
   "name": "Pizza",
   "image": "http://yourimageurl...",
   .
   .
   .
}
```

So what I would do is to display a new fragment or activity passing the object that the user clicked. In order to do so, this class must be Parcelable. This way you will have the data you need to display in the next screen, and if you need to make another request, let's say using the id of the Pizza, you can also do it.

To exemplify, let's say you have a "Meal" class, so you just have to make this class Parcelable:

```
@Parcelize
data class Meal(
   val id: Long,
   val name: String,
   val imageUrl: String
) : Parcelable
```

After this, in your item click callback, just call the fragment/activity you use to display selection info:

```
  fun onItemClickListener(meal: Meal) {
     val intent = Intent(this, MealDetailActivity::class.java)
     intent.putExtra("selected_meal", meal)
     startActivity(intent)
  }
```

And in your "MealDetailActivity" just recover your meal object and use it to populate your view or fetch the data you need.

Hope this helps, if not tell me and I will try to be more specific.

UPDATE: I add the Java solution.

The Meal class would be something like this:

```
public class Meal implements Parcelable {
    
    private long id;
    private String name;
    private String image;

    public Meal(long id, String name, String image) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.image = image;
    }

    protected Meal(Parcel in) {
        id = in.readLong();
        name = in.readString();
        image = in.readString();
    }

    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
        dest.writeLong(id);
        dest.writeString(name);
        dest.writeString(image);
    }

    @Override
    public int describeContents() {
        return 0;
    }

    public static final Creator<Meal> CREATOR = new Creator<Meal>() {
        @Override
        public Meal createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
            return new Meal(in);
        }

        @Override
        public Meal[] newArray(int size) {
            return new Meal[size];
        }
    };
}
```

As you can see, in Java the Parcelable is much more verbose (I strongly suggest you start coding in Kotlin :P). However, when you make a Java class implement the Parcelable interface, the AndroidStudio will ask you to add the Parcelable implementation for you (before this, you have to write the attributes you want this class to have). To clarify this, follow these steps:

1. Create a new Java class
2. Add the attributes that this class needs
3. Write `implements Parcelable`
4. In the red lamp, click it and select "Add Parcelable implementation".

Then, in your item click callback, just call the fragment/activity you use to display selection info:

```
public void onMealItemClick(Meal meal) {
  Intent intent = new Intent(this, MealDetailActivity.class);
  intent.putExtra("selected_meal", meal);
  startActivity(intent);
}
```

Finally, in your MealDetailActivity you can recover your Meal object:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle onSavedInstanceState) {
    Meal selectedMeal = getIntent().getParcelableExtra("selected_meal");
    // do the stuff you need to do with your selected item.
}
```

As I said, I suggest you check how Parcelable works, since you will use it a lot in the future.

Hope this helps, if it does please mark as resolved :)

Comment: can you show me this code in java please 

Comment: In Java quite similar, the biggest difference will be in the Parcelable implementation, since you won't be able to use the @Parcelize annotation. For this part, I suggest that you check the official documentation. I will update my answer with the java implementation.

Comment: is Kotlin easy to learn and better than java? little help

Comment: if I know java then kotlin will easy or normal or hard

Comment: I have a doubt let suppose if I want the name of the meal i.e. Pizza. How can I get the name of that meal. 

Comment: You can add getters and setters to the Meal class if you need them ;) And as for the kotlin questions, if you already know java changing to kotlin will be quite easy